# Spyder 4 code autocompletion with Jedi is (still) slow within the editor

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, code-completion

I am using `Spyder 4` with [`Jedi`](https://pypi.org/project/jedi/) for code autocompletion inside `Anaconda3`:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build
spyder                    4.1.4                    py37_0
spyder-kernels            1.9.2                    py37_0
jedi                      0.17.1                   py37_0
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py37_0
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0
ipython                   7.16.1           py37h5ca1d4c_0
python                    3.7.7                h81c818b_4
```

But the code completion within the editor is sometimes inefficient, like when typing `self.<tab>`. I find myself coding in `IPython 7.16.1` as it is very smooth and copying back to the editor. I have heard of the new `Kite` integration since December 2019, but it is a bit [fishy](https://qz.com/1043614/this-startup-learned-the-hard-way-that-you-do-not-piss-off-open-source-programmers/), which makes me ask: how can we make `Jedi` run faster in the editor? any better solutions/alternatives?

Comment: I have the same trouble with the default completion settings (not sure if that is Jedi).

Comment: @adr to the best of my knowledge yes, Jedi is the default autocompletion engine in Spyder as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We're aware that code completion with Jedi is slow for large files (i.e. more than 1000 lines of code). For now the only solution is to break down your files into smaller ones.

We hope to fix that in the future.

Comment: Are there any plans to speed up code completion in Spyder 5? I am often using Spyder to edit files over ssfs mounted drive and this makes code completion totally unusable. If my code uses an installed python package, it's locations should not matter at all. E.g., `import somepackage` then `somepackage.` code completion should not depend on where the current file is loaded from? Currently it does.

Comment: Yes, there are plans to do it during the first half of this year.

Answer (score 3):

Jabro, I completely agree with you.  Using spyder 4.1.5, jedi 0.17.1 the auto-completion in the editor window is unbearably slow, while the ipython console is just fine.  Here is a suggestion that helps my case quite a lot.  **Copy the file you are working on to the fastest storage medium you have in your machine.  Presumably a locally connected SSD.**  I found that even 100 line files that are on far-away file shares are incredibly slow to auto-complete.

To Spyder developers, please take a look at how high latency in reading/saving the file (>200ms) affects the auto-complete.   I have used Spyder for many years and hate to see it bogged down by this bug.

Comment: The latency is a network issue, not a Spyder one. So i don't know what we could do about it.